# Why Chart.js (type: time) display wrong labels

Tags: javascript, angular, chart.js, chart.js2

Chart.js don't want to show first month label, additional that framework render addition month label, who not exists.

I use ng2-charts with time type in Angular 7. In presented chart I have domains stats with period of 3 months. I check datasets and its really present 3 periods, no errors.
In graph I see first month label not presented, but with these chart add September label who not exist in dataset. Data points shows, only label not presented.
[Chart](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1UBfgFe82GBCIRBS609v6qJwQAXWhSeWi)
When I try to set minimum of x-Axis exactly like first month chart show its label but diagram start draw not from x-Axis "Zero".
I think my build-in functions make some errors but when I switch off all of these in options problem still exists.
[Chart with min of x-axis](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KDwF2EYW6zpcATqO5m4MCzIb2eQ7Jjne)

**Options (I disable my functions)**

```
let chartOptions = {
      type: 'line',
      options: {
        customBlock: {
          normalizeNumbers: Formatter.normalizeNumber,
          monthsLocale: this.months,
          groupMetric: this.groupMetric,
          measureUnits: this.measureUnits,
          tooltip: this.toolTip
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        legend: {
          display: true,
          position: 'bottom',
          labels: {
            usePointStyle: true,
            fontFamily: "'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif",
            fontStyle: "bold",
            fontColor: 'white',
            boxWidth: 8,
            padding: 20,
            // generateLabels: this.generateLegendLabels,

          },
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            id: 'Groups',
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'left',
            // scaleLabel: this.leftLabelOptions,
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              padding: 10,
              fontColor: 'white',
              fontSize: 10,
              // callback: this.generateDataYTicks
            },
            gridLines: {
              color: '#3C2D4C',
              borderDash: [5, 5],
              drawTicks: false
            }
          }, {
            id: 'Infopole',
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'right',
            // scaleLabel: this.rightLabelOptions,
            gridLines: {
              color: '#3C2D4C',
              display: false,
              drawBorder: true,
            },
            ticks: {
              min: 0,
              fontColor: 'white',
              fontSize: 10,
              // callback: this.generateInfopoleYTicks
            }
          }],
          xAxes: [
            {
              display: true,
              mirror: true,
              type: 'time',
              time: {
                unit: 'month',
                source: 'data'
              },
              distribution: 'series',
              ticks: {
                fontColor: 'white',
                fontSize: 10,
                // callback: this.generateXTicks
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        layout: {
          padding: {
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
          }
        },
        tooltips: {
          enabled: false,
          // custom: this.generateTooltip
        }
      }
    };

    return chartOptions;

  }
```

**I add data in next format**

```
dataset = {
  label: "string",
  data: [
    {x: new Date(timestamp), y: number}, ...
  ]
}
```